# WebDAV only working on one machine?

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I have implemented IT Hits WebDAV server on our company website. We a currently using a trial licence to develop the product which expires Sunday, September 07, 2014.

I have managed to get a working prototype working on my local build and I have checked it into our company TFS server.

It works perfectly on my machine and when people connect to my PC through the network it work OK too.

However when my manager has gotten latest and tested the new edit functionality on his local machine it will not work. I checked the error log there are no errors.

> My main question does the trial version of the WebDAV server only work
>   on one machine? Does it some how detect which machine the licence has been active on and restrict it to this machine.

If the licence can work on multiple machines do you have any suggestions to help debug the issue?

The log below is from the machine which does not work:

```
   [5] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 10:42:29 -----------------
[5] [OPTIONS] /DAV/cdef1072-d16a-4e42-a87c-301ded0b96c0/fcf65118-e733-40f6-807b-cdcde0e47df4/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: username=adrian
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
X-MSGETWEBURL: t
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[5] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
DAV : 1, 2, 3
Allow : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Public : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Accept-Ranges : bytes
MS-Author-Via : DAV

[5] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 10:42:33 Took 3828ms--------

[45] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 10:42:33 -----------------
[45] [HEAD] /DAV/cdef1072-d16a-4e42-a87c-301ded0b96c0/fcf65118-e733-40f6-807b-cdcde0e47df4/cbbh.docx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: username=adrian
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[45] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
Content-Type : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Last-Modified : Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length : 11231

[45] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 10:42:34 Took 1234ms--------

[49] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 10:42:35 -----------------
[49] [OPTIONS] /DAV/cdef1072-d16a-4e42-a87c-301ded0b96c0/fcf65118-e733-40f6-807b-cdcde0e47df4/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: username=adrian
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[49] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
DAV : 1, 2, 3
Allow : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Public : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Accept-Ranges : bytes
MS-Author-Via : DAV

[49] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 10:42:36 Took 1234ms--------
```

The next log below is from my working version:

```
[60] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 12:15:10 -----------------
[60] [OPTIONS] /DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: username=mark
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
X-MSGETWEBURL: t
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[60] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
DAV : 1, 2, 3
Allow : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Public : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Accept-Ranges : bytes
MS-Author-Via : DAV

[60] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 12:15:10 Took 640ms--------

[48] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 12:15:10 -----------------
[48] [HEAD] /DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/Test%20Document.docx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: username=mark
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[48] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
Content-Type : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Last-Modified : Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length : 11323

[48] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 12:15:11 Took 453ms--------

[54] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 12:15:11 -----------------
[54] [OPTIONS] /DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: username=mark
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[54] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
DAV : 1, 2, 3
Allow : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Public : COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Accept-Ranges : bytes
MS-Author-Via : DAV

[54] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 12:15:12 Took 468ms--------

[45] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 12:15:12 -----------------
[45] [LOCK] /DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/Test%20Document.docx
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 220
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Cookie: username=mark
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
Translate: f
Timeout: Second-3600
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[45] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><D:lockinfo xmlns:D="DAV:"><D:lockscope><D:exclusive/></D:lockscope><D:locktype><D:write/></D:locktype><D:owner><D:href>ORCHIDSOFT\Danial.Westmorland</D:href></D:owner></D:lockinfo>
[45] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
Lock-Token : <opaquelocktoken:94cd8ec7-b26e-4c14-9507-f6231a1812be>
Content-Type : application/xml; charset=utf-8

[45] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:prop xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:lockdiscovery>
    <d:activelock>
      <d:locktype>
        <d:write />
      </d:locktype>
      <d:lockscope>
        <d:exclusive />
      </d:lockscope>
      <d:depth>infinity</d:depth>
      <d:locktoken>
        <d:href>opaquelocktoken:94cd8ec7-b26e-4c14-9507-f6231a1812be</d:href>
      </d:locktoken>
      <d:timeout>Second-28799</d:timeout>
      <d:owner>ORCHIDSOFT\Danial.Westmorland</d:owner>
      <d:lockroot>
        <d:href>https://localhost:443/DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/Test%20Document.docx</d:href>
      </d:lockroot>
    </d:activelock>
  </d:lockdiscovery>
</d:prop>
[45] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 12:15:13 Took 844ms--------

[64] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 12:15:13 -----------------
[64] [GET] /DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/Test%20Document.docx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Cookie: username=mark; 88b20e20-4b54-4be9-ab03-4b434b9e4d1f=1001
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
Translate: f
Depth: 0
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[64] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
Content-Length : 11323
Accept-Ranges : bytes
Content-Type : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Last-Modified : Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT

[64] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 12:15:13 Took 500ms--------

[83] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 12:15:14 -----------------
[83] [PROPFIND] /DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/Test%20Document.docx
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 208
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Cookie: username=mark; 88b20e20-4b54-4be9-ab03-4b434b9e4d1f=1001
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Word 2013 (15.0.4631) Windows NT 6.2
Translate: f
Depth: 0
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[83] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><D:propfind xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:Office="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><D:prop><D:creationdate/><D:getlastmodified/><Office:modifiedby/></D:prop></D:propfind>
[83] HTTP/1.1 207 Multi-Status
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
Content-Type : application/xml; charset=utf-8

[83] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:response>
    <d:href>https://localhost:443/9917c323-7aae-4d06-8ebe-7349f9dd4c23</d:href>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
      <d:prop />
    </d:propstat>
    <d:propstat>
      <d:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</d:status>
      <d:prop>
        <modifiedby xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" />
      </d:prop>
      <d:responsedescription>Property was not found</d:responsedescription>
    </d:propstat>
  </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
[83] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 12:15:14 Took 579ms--------

[45] ----------------- Started: 13/08/2014 12:15:15 -----------------
[45] [HEAD] /DAV/07f23d4c-7b7c-4018-921b-18bb3f469f0d/eff37f65-4266-4f00-9993-5529d8d9edaf/Test%20Document.docx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Cookie: username=mark
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Microsoft Office Existence Discovery
X-IDCRL_ACCEPTED: t

[45] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34014 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.7.1780.0 (Evaluation License)
Content-Type : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Last-Modified : Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length : 11323

[45] ----------------- Finished: 13/08/2014 12:15:16 Took 438ms--------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out the issue.

When I checked the IIS server on the PC that was not working I noticed that WebDAV Authoring Rules an installed feature. I then checked my PC and this was not installed.

http://i2.iis.net/media/7427780/installing-and-configuring-webdav_webdav_home_pane3.jpg?cdn_id=2012-08-15-001

Once I removed this it worked for me.

I removed it by creating the following .cmd file in notepad:

```
start dism.exe /online /disable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebDAV
```

Answer (score -2):

All IT Hit products, including IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine for .Net are fully functional and does not have any limitations. It should be working on any machine and on more than one machine with a trial license.

Please take a look at how to deploy the sample server shipped with WebDAV Server Engine to IIS here: [How to Configure Your WebDAV Server in IIS](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/iis/configuring_webdav_server).
Even though each WebDAV server has its own specifics and this guide may not be applicable in your case, it helps to understand the typical deployment scenario and security configuration.

Here are some recommendations about haw to understand what is going wrong:

1. Examine WebDAV requests with a Fiddler tool or any other debugging
   proxy. While all requests that reached the WebDAV server Engine are
   logged, if the request failed before hitting the Engine, you will not
   see it in a log. Usually this happens if the request failed during
   authentication stage.

   Note that to capture requests using Fiddler on 'localhost' you must
   use 'localhost.fiddler' instead of 'localhost' when connecting to
   server, for example: http://localhost.fiddler:1234.
2. Run Ajax integration tests. Just create a WebDAV project with Visual Studio to get the tests page. Than specify Url of your WebDAV server right on a tests page. Are there any failed tests?
3. Exclude any client side issues. There could be issues with
   client software that you are using, including with Microsoft
   miniredirector. Try to access server from any other machine. To get
   the idea if the problem is on the client or server side try also to
   reproduce the issue on ajaxbrowser.com.